# drawing multiple layouts inside a view

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-canvas

I have a view/layout that I need to render multiple times on a canvas. Call it stats. So I create a `stats.xml` file and lay out my views in it. Then in the `.java` file, I inflate the layout and edit the appropriate child views of `stats`. At this point how do I add the view to my canvas at a specific location? Actually I already tried but my view is NOT showing. Here is the code:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.stats, null, false);
        addDateToTextView(date, (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp));
        parentView.setX(50);
        parentView.setY(yOffset);
        parentView.draw(canvas);
```

I am using the canvas from onDraw

Comment: After setting `parentView.layout(l,r,t,b)` my view is NOW visible. but it has no content. only the background shows. What happened to the child views?

Comment: I just read that a way to get the children views to draw is to call `parentView.dispatchDraw(canvas)`. But eclipse says that dispatchDraw is private. So any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

So I find a crappy solution. I have to call `layout` and `.draw(canvas)` on every child view. I am convinced there must be a more sensible solution.

Comment: I just read that a way to get the children views to draw is to call parentView.dispatchDraw(canvas). But eclipse says that dispatchDraw is private. So any ideas how to get this to work? – Cote Mounyo just now